# Regular expression for comma delimited string with length constraints

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to build a regular expression to match these criteria but I am not getting it.

- Its a comma delimited string (a list of user ids)
- Each user id contains A-Z0-9 and length 1-64 `([A-Za-z0-9]{1,64})`
- How do I use this and build a regular expression that has comma (optional if there is
  only one ID) and repeated userIDs?

so far, I have this `"^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,64}+,?\\s*)+$"` and `"^(([a-zA-Z0-9]){1,64}+,?\\s*)+$"` and it doesn't honor the length

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,64}(?:,\\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,64})*$`, see [this video of mine](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XU-ode0Mwek&lc=UgwrAGX6Xt_EHoRa-AR4AaABAg).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `,\\s` isn't what you meant right :o?

Comment: @MDR I did not. OP did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the pattern that follows the following scheme:

```
^[pattern](?:[separator][pattern])*$
```

In this concrete case, you can use

```js
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,64}(?:,\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,64})*$
```

If you allow spaces before the comma, add `\s*` before `,`.

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,64}` - one to 64 alphanumeric chars
- `(?:,\s*[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,64})*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `,` - a comma
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,64}` - one to 64 alphanumeric chars
- `$` - end of string.

See more about this validation technique in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XU-ode0Mwek&lc=UgwrAGX6Xt_EHoRa-AR4AaABAg).

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for, The explanation in the second half of your post wasvery helpful in understanding it. Thanks for that.